# Impossibility of making an "If and only if statement" stronger?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Is it impossible to prove a stronger version of an "if an only if" result?

It seems to me that the answer would be "no" because to strengthen "$A$ iff $B$" I would need to either weaken $A$ or $B$. Suppose I weaken $A$ (so $A$ no longer holds but some condition implied by $A$ holds). Then $B$ cannot hold since $A$ is necessary for $B$ (i.e. $B\implies A$, so $\text{not } A\implies\text{not }B$).

So basically, if there is an "if and only if" result, in order to improve upon it would both $A$ and $B$ need to be weakened?

Thanks

Comment: What is the definition of making a statement "stronger"?

Comment: What about $r \implies (p \iff q)$

Comment: @Math_QED No, that will make it weaker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you weaken both $A$ and $B$ you simply get something that is neither stronger nor weaker than the original. For example,

> I take a red umbrella to work if and only if it rains on a Tuesday

neither implies nor is implied by

> I take an umbrella to work if and only if it rains on a weekday

(both A and B have been weakened).

The only way I can think of to make a stronger statement than $A\Longleftrightarrow B$ is to add something to it, for example finding a third condition $C$ such that $A$, $B$ and $C$ are all equivalent.

Comment: $A \leftrightarrow B \leftrightarrow C$ is neither stronger nor weaker than $A \leftrightarrow B$: when $A$ is true, and $B$ and $C$ are false, then  $A \leftrightarrow B$ is false, but $A \leftrightarrow B \leftrightarrow C$ is true. On the other hand, when they are all false, then $A \leftrightarrow B$ is true, but $A \leftrightarrow B \leftrightarrow C$ is false.

Comment: @Bram28 I don't know how you are interpreting $A\Longleftrightarrow B\Longleftrightarrow C$, but I intended it to mean "$A$, $B$ and $C$ are pairwise equivalent", as in $x=y=z$.

Comment: I see. So it would be $(A \leftrightarrow B) \land (B \leftrightarrow C) \land (A \leftrightarrow C)$. Yes, that would indeed be a stronger claim (since we conjunct something to the original claim).  But you don't write that as $A \leftrightarrow B \leftrightarrow C$ ... that's a different claim.

Comment: @Bram28 I didn't write it as $A\leftrightarrow B\leftrightarrow C$. I wrote it as $A\Longleftrightarrow B\Longleftrightarrow C$. It doesn't surprise me that $A\leftrightarrow B\leftrightarrow C$ means something different.

Comment: I took the $\Leftrightarrow$ in the OP, and also your answer, to mean the biconditional implication. I prefer to use $\leftrightarrow$ since I use $\Leftrightarrow$ for logical equivalence. Indeed,  $A \Leftrightarrow B \Leftrightarrow C$ would not be a proper way to use $\Leftrightarrow$ when it is meant as logical equivalence. So, I am pretty sure I mean the same thing with $A \leftrightarrow B \leftrightarrow C$ as you and the OP mean by $A \Leftrightarrow B \Leftrightarrow C$. And, that statement is true when an even number of the propositions $A$, $B$, and $C$ are false.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime "$A\iff B\iff C$" (regardless of what kind of double arrow you use) is always as far as I know interpreted as "$(A\iff B)\iff C$" (note that the order of parentheses doesn't matter). That's quite different from "$(A\iff B)\wedge (B\iff C)\wedge (A\iff C)$."

Answer (score 3):

You're right: just working with the left or right side cannot result in a stronger statement.  However, something like:

$$(A \leftrightarrow B) \land C$$

is a stronger claim than

$$A \leftrightarrow B$$

Answer (score 0):

In practice, the way to "strenghten" an equivalence is often the following: Suppose we proved
$$
A \iff B.
$$
Now it's often the case that this equivalence is a 'corollary' of a more general result that we later discover. I.e. there are statements $A^-, B^-$ for which we can prove
$$
A^- \iff B^-
$$
and for which we (usually for trivial reasons) have
$$
A \wedge B^-  \implies B \text{ and } B \wedge A^- \implies A.
$$

In this case the proof of $A^- \iff B^-$ can be viewed as a strengthening of the previous result that $A \iff B$.

The way this usually goes is that $A,B$ are 'global' statements and $A^-, B^-$ are 'localized' version of this. (This came up recently in a discussion about strong cardinals but I don't think that going into details will be very helpful to this thread.)

Comment: Why can this be viewed as a strengthening?